# SSO using Azure AD on iOS (Safari/Chrome) causes infinite login loop (.NET 5, C#)

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

A new website using Azure AD SSO for authentication and authorization causes infinite loop after successful login on iOS devices (Safari/Chrome browsers). Login works perfectly fine on Android, Win10 and Linux devices using FireFox, Chrome and Edge browsers.

The problem is persistent, and I'm able to reproduce easily using the following steps:

1. User removes all history from the browser (clean-up to start with a clean slate)
2. User browses to website, gets redirected to login.microsoftonline.com to login, due to Authorize attribute
3. User logs in, and gets redirected back to website. User is now logged in.
4. This is where it gets weird. Without doing any action on the website, if the user refreshes the page, which is the root page ('/'), the user now experiences infinite loop on login.microsoftonline.com. After about 10-15 seconds the Microsoft SSO page says its unable to log the user in to the website.
5. If the user browses back to the website manually, by entering its URL, the website loads fine and the user is logged in.
6. If the user closes the website and reopens it after a short while, lets say 15 minutes, the user ends up being stuck in the infinite loop again. Manually browsing to the website after receiving the 'cannot log you in'-message does show the user is logged in again, meaning that the authentication and authorization works.

(steps 4 and 5 can be skipped, it just speeds up debugging having the error show at step 4)

The question is, why does the website gets stuck in the infinite login loop? And why does this happen on iOS products (using Safari/Chrome) only?

---

What I've tried so far:

- Old issues show that iOS 12 has had issues regarding cookies. Trying the examples suggested by those solutions, including the response from MS Azure AD team, does not fix my issues. My test devices are using iOS 15 with Safari 14.x.
- I've removed the 'Roles'-part of the websites' Authorize attribute assuming it could be an issue regarding roles, but that didn't fix it either.
- Updating the NuGet packages to the latest version (.NET 5.0.12, Microsoft.Identity.Web 1.21.0).

---

The website uses the following example as the source; However I have not tested it the same problem exists using the example itself.
[Implementation example used (AzureAd sample)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2)

```
// appsettings.json:
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mydomain.com",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxx",
    "ClientId": "yyyyyyy",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-callback-oidc"
},
```

```
// StartUp.cs:
services
    .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(configuration => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", configuration));

services
    .AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    })
    // Maintain property names during serialization. See:
    // https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    });

services
    .AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Comment: We you able to find a solution to this issue? 
PS: it might be related to this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665419